# Not able to update firebase realtime database in angularjs (web)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code to update a record in firebase.

```
$scope.EditBrand = function(brand)  {
    var key = brand.id;
    var fredNameRef = firebase.database().ref('all-brands/' + key);

    fredNameRef.set(brand, function(error) {
      if (error) {
        alert ('some error')
      } else {
        alert ('updated')
      }
    });
}
```

I checked the key, and its coming correct.

But when calling this function this is the error.

angular.js:12477Error: Firebase.update failed: First argument contains an invalid key ($$hashKey) in path /$$hashKey. Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"
    at Error (native)

What is wrong with my code or logic??

Comment: I think you have an invalid key/id. Is `$$hashKey` your brand id ? If it is, FIrebase does not accept '$' in keys.

Comment: @Odonno, My brand id String like 23, 34, 45 etc

Comment: According to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/pI0IgNHKjxw, you should create a temporary object to avoid fields generated by angular. So, add this line in your method : `var brandObject = angular.fromJson(angular.toJson(brand));` and use `brandObject` in the rest of the method.

Comment: Thanks. Its working now. Please post your answer, so i will accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/pI0IgNHKjxw, you should create a temporary object to avoid fields generated by angular. So, add this line in your method : `var brandObject = angular.fromJson(angular.toJson(brand));` and use `brandObject` in the rest of the method.